# jQuery : pass argument to ajax error function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been making some ajax function these days, and I'm facing a small problem. I have a function that calls an ajax. I want to give it a value, and return that function when the request is done. How do I either:

- Trigger the return from the ajax sub functions
- Wait for the "answer" var to change and then return it

Here's the spirit (indeed, it cannot work) :

```
var answer = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: "validate/"+id,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'field' : value},
        success: function(data) {
            //noty({text: data, type: 'success'});
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions){
            noty({text: xhr.status + " : " + xhr.responseText, type: 'error'});
            answer = "error";
        } 
    });

return answer;
```

Thank you!

Comment: You make the function accept a callback, which is called inside the error handler and pass the `answer` value to it, like you do it with `noty`. You cannot return a value from an asynchronous function call. Or better yet: Use deferred objects: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: Wow, that kind of way to do it is so strange to me... I'll try it

Comment: Well, you *can* if you make a blocking call, but it would be unwise, as it blocks browser UI for the period of request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't `return` values from an AJAX function, as an AJAX request happens *asynchronously* (think how long it takes to retrieve a remote webpage).

Instead you need to provide a callback (a function which is executed *when* the request completes):

```
function ajaxFunction(onComplete) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "validate/"+id,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'field' : value},
        success: function(data) {
            //noty({text: data, type: 'success'});
            onComplete(data);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions){
            noty({text: xhr.status + " : " + xhr.responseText, type: 'error'});
            onComplete(error);
        }
    }
}
```

You'd then pass a function as a parameter to `ajaxFunction`, which will receive the response from the AJAX request.

```
ajaxFunction(function (answer) {
    // do something with answer
});
```

As you need an `id` and `value` parameter, you could add those to arguments of the `ajaxFunction` method.

Comment: What if I need to block the function that calls that ajax function? Like if it's necessary for it to wait?

Comment: @GabrielTheron: It should **never** be necessary for it to wait. Show a loading spinner or tell the user to make a cup of tea.

Comment: ^^ Yeah, well, in that instance, the request should directly condition the next action of the user, and should also be extremely quick... But I get the point, let's make 'em wait

Answer (score 0):

Use `async: false` flag - see the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation for reference.

Note that in jQuery 1.8, the use of `async` will be deprecated.

```
var answer = null;

$.ajax({
    url: "validate/"+id,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'field' : value},
    success: function(data) {
        //noty({text: data, type: 'success'});
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions){
        noty({text: xhr.status + " : " + xhr.responseText, type: 'error'});
        answer = "error";
    },
    async: false
});

return answer;
```

Comment: Thanks! How do you replace it in 1.8?

Comment: The use of `async` is ***highly*** discouraged... it was deprecated for a reason.

Comment: Then how should I keep my function waiting? In that instance it is required to

Comment: Simply make your calls asynchronous. If a code have to be executed after success/failure than add it to `success:`/`failure:` callbacks. It's just a mater of organizing the code.